# Android/Firebase - NullPointerException ao definir objeto Query

Tags: java, android, firebase

Olá,
Estou com um problema durante a leitura dos dados no Firebase. Uso o Android Studio 3.0 e Java.
Consigo me conectar no banco, pegar a instância, o usuário logado, mas não estou conseguindo ler os atributos do nó selecionado.

A estrutura do banco é essa aqui:

```
{
  "user" : {
    "YWxsYW5AbmVyb3MuY29tLmJy" : {
      "active" : true,
      "id" : "YWxsYW5AbmVyb3MuY29tLmJy",
      "userEmail" : "allan@neros.com.br",
      "userName" : "Allan Neros",
    }
  }
}
```

O que pretendo é pegar todos os children do nó "YWxsYW5AbmVyb3MuY29tLmJy".

O código Java que escrevi para resolver é este aqui:

```
    FirebaseDatabase dbsFirebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference refFirebase  = dbsFirebase.getReference();
    System.out.println("Reference: " + refFirebase.toString());

    //strUserId é uma String que retorna o id do nó, e está funcionando corretamente
    Query mQuery = refFirebase.child("user").orderByChild("id").equalTo(strUserId).limitToFirst(1);
    System.out.println("Query: " + mQuery.getRef().getKey());

    //A aplicação encerra nesta linha, nem passa pelo onDataChange
    mQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            loggedUser = new User();
            //User loggedUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            loggedUser.setId(dataSnapshot.child("id").getValue().toString());
            loggedUser.setUserName(dataSnapshot.child("userName").getValue().toString());
            loggedUser.setUserEmail(dataSnapshot.child("userEmail").getValue().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            System.out.println("Erro: " + databaseError.getDetails());
        }
    });
```

A classe User tem os mesmos atributos do banco.

Depois desses códigos, estou definindo os TextViews da Activity com as informações do loggedUser, mas como ele está vazio, recebo um NullPointerException (o que faz sentido, por que o objeto loggedUser não está sendo criado, pois não entra no onDataChange).
Eu montei o código com o que achei na documentação do Firebase e em exemplos coletados na internet (incluindo posts aqui do StackOverflow).

Alguma pista de por que este erro está acontecendo? Existe uma forma melhor de obter estas informações?

Agradeço a atenção e a ajuda dispensadas.

Comment: se ´mQuery` realmente é null, não deveria estar chegando na mlinha que cria o listener, pois antes tem um System.out.println e já deveria parar lá. Por favor, confirme a linha exata da exceção e a mensagem de erro.

Comment: Faço das palavras do @PabloAlmeida as minhas, confirme a linha da exceção

Comment: @PabloAlmeida, obrigado pelo retorno.  
mQuery não está nulo quando passa pelo mQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener().  No entanto, depois de passar por essa parte (onde devo pegar os elementos do objeto loggedUser para colocar nos TextViews da Activity), no debugger, o mQuery fica nulo.  Tem algo a ver com o escopo do objeto? (o mQuery está sendo instanciado no onCreate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quer pegar todos os child da referência "YWxsYW5AbmVyb3MuY29tLmJy", aponte a propria referencia para esta Key, e depois adiciona um event listener diretamente na reference

```
refFirebase.child("users").child(strUserId);
refFirebase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //Supondo que aqui a classe é igual ao seu nó no Firebase
            User loggedUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

            //Executa o que precisar com o loggedUser aqui.
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            System.out.println("Erro: " + databaseError.getDetails());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Olá, obrigado pelo retorno.Substituí meu código pelo que você colocou e no debugger o refFirebase aparece com as chaves mas sem os elementos ({}). Se eu debugar o caminho aparece certo o /user/strUserId.  Eu achei que ler o banco fosse algo simples, não tão trabalhoso como está sendo.

Comment: É porque a reference somente traz o valor dentro do evento (que eh assíncrono). A entidade/nó mesmo é a conversão do dataSnapshot no onDataChange do evento.